# How set margins to print when pdf files are inserted?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, geometry, pdfpages

I am using book style to prepare a material (which has to be printed and binded) which contains so many pdf files.

To include the pdf files I am using `\includepdf` options by using the package `pdfpages`.

The pdf files shows in the properties that it is using `US Letter, Portrait (216 × 279 mm)`. I tried to fit my page in the same size but could not.

> How to fit the pdfpages into my page size.
>
> And how to set the margins for the binding and printing purpose. (Means I should able to set my margin on my own according to the publisher's need when I need)

Here is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
    
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={297mm,210mm}}
    
\begin{document}
   
\includepdf[pages=2-last]{preface1}
   
\end{document}
```

### My output: (in this it is aligned top left)

[image]

### To be more clear about my requirements,

1. I am adding a cover page and creating a content page using `addcontentsline` command before `\includepdf` option.
2. Title page.
3. Acknowledgement.
4. And the pdf pages (all are in US letter).
5. Report.

All are prepared in the latex only except the inserting the pdfpages.

So, if I get a suggestion to design my book in a appropriate size which looks better while I am including these pages, I would be grateful.

Comment: To be clear: do you want to impose US Letter over A4?

Comment: not exactly. but if I can design my book itself according to the pdf pages inserted I will be happy. Because I dont want extra spaces. It should be a book like a typed one only(not like pdfpages inserted)..@egreg

Comment: Sorry, but you aren't giving enough information.

Comment: Kindly see my updated question.@egreg

Comment: I have used `offset=15mm 0mm` in the `\includepdf` option. but I am not convinced with that solution.

Comment: @egreg The pdfs which I am including is from the following. http://repository.uwyo.edu/ela/vol29/iss1/ This may help  to be more clear about my requirements.

Comment: So why don't you use `letterpaper` rather than `a4paper` if that's a better match? Or use a custom size which is equal to US letter with 15mm added to the width (or whatever) to allow for binding and then tell `geometry` about the offset? I'm not really clear about what exactly you want to do here. US letter and A4 are not just different sizes but different shapes. So it cannot look as it would if just printed if you have to scale it to fit paper with a different height/width ratio.